# FilZilla shows physical path of ftp folder, any workaround?

Tags: ftp, chroot

I am using vsftpd as ftp server on rhel 5. I published a folder using ftp and try to access that folder using ftp client FileZilla. The problem is that filezilla shows physical path of ftp folder. This can be a security concern.

Please suggest me any workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `chroot_local_user=YES` instead of `chroot_list_enable=YES` in your configuration file

Answer (score 0):

If you `chroot` the users connected using FTP, they will be able only to see their home (chrooted) folder.

Comment: Do you suggesting me chroot_list_enable=YES. But this not making any difference.